# Call Redis (or other db) from within Spray Route

Tags: scala, akka, spray, jedis

I am trying to figure out the best way to establish a Redis Pool and then make calls to Redis from within a Spray route.  I want to make sure that I can use the connection pool for Redis connections.  What would be the best way to instantiate the pool and use it within my spray routes? Is there a better way to establish a "global" pool that can be used? Should I create an actor instead and use that to make the redis calls? I am obviously a bit ignorant here.

Crude Redis Client:

```
object RedisClient {

  val pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost")

  def getValue(key: String): String= {

    try{
      val jedis = pool.getResource()

      //returns redis value
      jedis.get(key)
    }
  }


}
```

Route that ends up calling a function that uses the Redis Client

```
trait DemoService extends HttpService {

  val messageApiRouting =
        path("summary" / Segment / Segment) { (dataset, timeslice) =>
          onComplete(getSummary(dataset, timeslice)) {
            case Success(value) => complete(s"The result was $value")
            case Failure(ex) => complete(s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
          }
        }

  def getSummary(dataset: String, timeslice: String): Future[String] = Future {
    val key = dataset + timeslice
    RedisClient.getValue(key)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the Jedis client is not non-blocking and async. So you may not get all the benefits of using Spray if you use a blocking client. I would suggest looking at [Rediscala](https://github.com/etaty/rediscala).

Second I would delegate the actual interaction to another actor which has a RedisClient interacting with your Redis instance/cluster.

Finally, you can `complete` a Spray route by giving it a `Future`. This essentially means that your entire pipeline will be async and non-blocking.

NOTE: Redis is still single threaded and I don't think there is anyway around that AFAIK.

In general, you should use a *reactive driver* if possible (e.g., [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/news/2015/02/20/slick-3.0.0-RC1-released.html), [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) )

Comment: Soumya Thanks for all the info.  I will take a look.  Really appreciate the response.